# How to convert Oracle TO_NUMBER to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I am migrating some SQL scripts from Oracle to SQL Server and have come across an issue when trying to convert Oracles `TO_NUMBER` into T-SQL code. Looked through the web for some time but never found the answer but they all say to convert hex using `CAST` or `CONVERT` with `VARBINARY`.

An example of the issue I am getting is below.

In Oracle:

```
select
    to_number( '000000000000000000001111', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' )
from
    dual
```

returns 4369

When trying to use T-SQL `CONVERT`:

```
select
    CONVERT(VARBINARY, '000000000000000000001111')
```

returns 0x303030303030303030303030303030303030303031313131

and

```
select
    CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, '000000000000000000001111'))
```

returns 825307441

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

TSQL has binary literals, so you can write it like this:

```
select  CONVERT(INT, 0x000000000000000000001111)
```

outputs

```
4369
```

If you are starting with a hex string, you can use convert with the [binary style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles) of 1, or 2, so

```
 select convert(int, convert(varbinary(1024),'000000000000000000001111', 2))
```

outputs

```
4369
```

Comment: Beat me to it as I had to take a phone call!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work.

```
select convert(bigint, convert(Varbinary(MAX), '000000000000000000001111',2))
```